# How can I express that something "appears" a certain way?

Tags: usage, verbes

I was recently at a showcase for Montreal's new *Azur* metro cars that would be on tracks starting 2014. I walked into one of the demo cars they were showing and noticed that there appeared to be less seats in the new cars than in the current ones.

I wanted to ask one of the STM showcasers about this; specifically, I wanted to say

> *"It appears as though there are less seats here than in the current metro. Are there less seats?"*

I didn't know how to say this so I expressed it much less proficiently, but I'd still like to know how I can say the way I wanted to. Specifically, how can I tell someone that something "appears" a certain way? I'll give some examples to show what I'm talking about:

- "It (appears as though)/(looks like)/(seems like) there are less seats here than in the current metro. Are there less seats?"
- "It (appears as though)/(looks like)/(seems like) you haven't slept in days! Are you alright?"
- It (appears as though)/(looks like)/(seems like) all the bathrooms here are occupied. We can go to the bar across the street."
- "It (appears as though)/(looks like)/(seems like) they finally launched the French Language Stack Exchange site."

So how can I express this kind of sentence accurately in French? (And for anyone wondering, it's two less seats).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The common idiom is *on dirait que* ([TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dire): I.B.1.a.γ). It is followed by a verb in the indicative mood.

> On dirait qu'il y a moins de sièges¹ ici que dans le métro actuel. Y a-t-il effectivement moins de sièges ?

Other impersonal constructions are possible. Avoiding the impersonal *on* makes for slightly more formal writing. Another common idiom is *il semblerait que*, followed by the subjunctive.

> *Il semblerait qu'il y ait ici moins de places assises que dans le métro actuel. Est-ce effectivement le cas ?*

Variants include *il semble que* (a bit stronger than *il semblerait*, as the use of the conditional mood gives less weight to the semblance), and *il apparaît que* (rather strong: you do not expect contradiction, and rather formal: you wouldn't use it in everyday conversation, but it's what you would write in a formal report).

Like in English, personal formulations are also possible. Here are two possible translations with a construction similar to “this metro seems to have fewer seats than the current one”. The first is more formal than the second.

> *Ce métro semble disposer de moins de sièges que les rames actuelles.*
> *Ce métro a l'air d'avoir moins de sièges que le métro actuel.*

Your other examples would use similar phrasings.

> It appears as though you haven't slept in days! Are you all right?
> *On dirait tu n'as pas dormi depuis des jours ! Ça va bien ?*
> *Tu as l'air de ne pas avoir dormi depuis plusieurs jours ! Tu n'es pas bien ?*
>
> It looks like all the bathrooms here are occupied. We can go to the bar across the street.
> *On dirait que les toilettes sont toutes occupées. Nous pouvons aller au bar en face.*
>
> It looks like they finally launched the French Language Stack Exchange site.
> *On dirait que le site Stack Exchange sur la langue française a démarré.*
> *Apparemment, le site Stack Exchange sur le français a démarré.*

(*Apparemment* is a bit stronger, it indicates that you do not expect a refutation.)

In English, you can denote a specific method of perception through a verb. This is often not possible in French: if the method of perception is important, it will usually be conveyed through a complement or a different phrasing.

> Your voice sounds strained. Have you been crying?
> *Tu as l'air enroué. Tu as pleuré ?*
>
> This tastes like cinnamon.
> *On dirait de la cannelle.*
> *Ça a un goût de cannelle.*
>
> Something smells rotten. (figuratively: there's trouble brewing)
> *Ça sent le roussi.*

If the reason why you think something is true is that you've been told, rather than your observation, you can use the verb *paraître* in the impersonal form.

> I heard from someone that the next metro will have fewer seats.
> *Il paraît que le prochain métro aura moins de sièges.*

¹  <sub>ou : *de places assises*</sub>

Comment: Très bonne réponse. Pour "It looks like they finally launched the French Language Stack Exchange site.", on peut aussi dire " Il parait que..."

Answer (score 6):

I would say there are two main ways of expressing this idea in French, namely "*il semble (que)*" (perhaps literally translated as "it seems (that)") and "*on dirait que*" (literally "one would say that"). "It appears as though" can be translated as "*il appert que*", but it is a very literary phrasing and I do not recommend using it.

"*Il semble (que)*" is more formal than "*on dirait que*", but absolutely acceptable (and said) in casual conversations. The opposite if of course not quite true. I would however be more tempted to use the informal tone when talking to someone about how they look, like if your example.

> On dirait que tu n'as pas dormi depuis des jours! Est-ce que tout va bien?

As for the metro car question you could have used either phrasing:

> Il semble y avoir moins de places assises dans les nouveaux wagons, est-ce bien le cas?
>   *or*
>   On dirait qu'il y a moins de places assises dans les nouveaux wagons. Est-ce que c'est le cas?

The case would be similar for your other examples.

Comment: Actually the literal translation for *on dirait que...* would be *one would say that...*.

Comment: @Jez Very true indeed, I shall change it.

Comment: *Il appert*? Ah, from the verb *apparoir*. I have never heard or even read this verb. In France, it would not be understood. We might use *il apparaît que* (from *apparaître*), it is idiomatic in this kind of context and rather formal. Is *apparoir* used in Québec?

Comment: @Gilles It is not really used, no, but I have a translator friend who uses that phrase in some of his written communications. I put it up there to point out that it exists, but as I said, I really don't recommend using it.